# Key path value type 'FetchedResults<NotesHeader>' cannot be converted to contextual type 'FetchRequest<NotesHeader>'

Tags: swiftui, xcode14

I am new to SwiftUI (using XCode 14)
I get the error after refactoring my code, taking logic out of my view (which used to work)
XCode does not present me with an error on any particular line (so I know exactly which line is at fault) but rather displays the error looking at the failed build log.

Totally lost and any advice would be appreciated.

The only lines I can think of maybe causing the issue is the declaration of the fetch happening in my class ...

```
    @Published @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "favourite == %@", true as NSNumber), animation: Animation.default) var favouriteNotes: FetchedResults<NotesHeader>
    @Published @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "favourite == %@", false as NSNumber), animation: Animation.default) var notes: FetchedResults<NotesHeader>
```

Again, totally new to SwiftUI ... totally lost ... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can’t combine wrappers. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) There is a lot more wrong with what you are trying to do than just the wrappers. If you don’t start with the basics you will fight an uphill battle.

Comment: "Trying to run before you can walk" ... so now things seem out of control and overwhelming... I get it.
Appreciate the slap (in a positive way) ... It's back to the drawing board for me I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Got this sorted now ...

Trying to refactor the code lead to issues on something like ...

```
@Published @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "favourite == %@", true as NSNumber), animation: Animation.default) var favouriteNotes: FetchedResults<NotesHeader>
@Published @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "favourite == %@", false as NSNumber), animation: Animation.default) var notes: FetchedResults<NotesHeader>
```

What I didn't realise at the time is that while that code (without the @Publish) of course would work in a view ... it DOES NOT work that way when fetching core data in a class.

A YouTube video by Swiftful Thinking got me on the right track and now all is well.
Link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPQkpxtgalY&t=613s

Best of luck

Comment: The point of the @ property wrappers is so you don't need to use a class and can use struct value types which is the whole reason we use Swift. Also that video is talks about MVVM which is the wrong approach for SwiftUI I recommend watching Apple's WWDC videos, e.g. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/

Comment: Understood. Thanks for taking the time.  Much appreciated.